# Why is this group clause not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Payment` model with 5 rows. 4 of them with same user_id and one that is different. I try to group those results by user_id. It should return two results, however when trying this I always get the five results. Any idea why?

(I'm using Postgres)

```
Payment.find(:all, group: "user_id,id").count
=> 5
```

Also tried

```
Payment.find(:all, group: "id,user_id").count
=> 5
```

**Updated:** If I do not add the "user_id" I'm getting this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "payments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments"  GROUP BY user_id
               ^
: SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments"  GROUP BY user_id
```

**Updated 2:** This query

```
Payment.joins(:user).select('payments.id,users.username,payments.user_id,payments.token,payments.period_start_at,payments.amount_cents,payments.currency').group("user_id")
```

returns `PG::Error: ERROR:  column "payments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT payments.id,users.username,payments.user_id,payments....
               ^`

If I add "payments.id" to the group clause it will not group them by user_id. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no way you can group it by the `id`, as the `id` is probably a `serial` unique key on your table. Group only by `user_id`.

**Updated**

Aparently you are using `rails v 2.3.*` or something. Also, this is database knowledge. The query in `SQL` would be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), user_id FROM payments GROUP BY user_id
#=> user_id | count
    10        2
    3         1
    4         10
```

This will give you the number of payments certain user have. To translate this to a `ActiveRecord` query, you have to do:

```
Payment.count(:group => :user_id)
```

Comment: Use a combination of `select` and `group`. Or just use `group`. `Payment.group(:user_id).count`.

Comment: Canot use `Payment.group(:user_id).count` on postgres. Will try with select

Comment: Using select does not seem to work. Please see my updated question again.

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping by `id`. The `id` is unique. You'll necessarily have 5 groups, with one record per group. You cannot (meaningfully) group by `id`.

You're also using the very dated `find(:all, ...)` syntax. Use `Payment.group("user_id")` instead.

Comment: Ask a different question, don't fundamentally alter the meaning of your existing question.

Comment: why not? that sounds a bit gross

Comment: It's about producing good content, not interactively debugging your specific problem.

Comment: Ok, but you haven't provided any answer to my postgres question.

Comment: `Payment.group("user_id")` does not work on postgres. This `Payment.select('payments.id').group("user_id")` neither work.